# React event method assigning object to too many properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state, javascript-objects

So I'm trying to assign an object to an object property. I have found mild success, but the object is being assigned incorrectly. I am mapping over an array to show cards.

There are big cards, and small cards. Big cards can have a predetermined amount and type of small cards assigned to them. You can have multiple of the same big cards in a deck. Big cards are stored in an array

My big cards have an object property:

```
upgrades: {
  preterminedSmallCard: null,
  preterminedSmallCard: null
}
```

On click, I'm trying to add, based on a unique id for each Big card in the array, a small card to the slot.

Instead of adding it to a single instance in the array, it adds it to every big card with the same name. If its a different name, it doesn't add it.

Here is my code with pointed comments:

```
addUpgradeHandler = (card) => {
    //determines which upgrade type to add - console.logging properly
    const upgradeType = this.props.match.params.type;

    //finding the index of targeted ship
    const shipIndex = this.props.shipInfo.findIndex(index => {
        /** 
        * Router passes the id of the targeted ship, the compared against
        * returns true to the targeted ship, false for the ones not targeted
        * ID's generated with npm package uniqID - unique id for each instance in array
        **/
        return (index.id === this.props.match.params.id);
    });

    console.log(shipIndex); //evaluates properly to the target index position

    //mapping the state to a copy
    const newShips = [...this.props.shipInfo];

    //targeting the upgrades property inside of the correct index pos
    const upgrades = newShips[shipIndex].upgrades;

    console.log(upgrades); //returns only one index pos of the state with the upgrade equipped

    const currentPoints = this.props.points;

    //checking if adding the card will bust the max points allowed
    if (currentPoints + card.points < 400) {

        console.log(upgrades[upgradeType]); // returns one object, the value stored in the proper place
        /**
         * Issue starts here
         * - card -> represents object that the map below is, issue persists if object is explicitly written
         * assigns upgrade card object to the correct property type, but for every ship with the same name
         * The name of the ship is not being evaluated anywhere in this function
         **/
        //not intended

        upgrades[upgradeType] = card;
    }      
}
```

Other strange things:

- I delete the big card from the array by splicing using the same comparison as the above, and only splices one, in the desired manner.
- After splicing from the array, if I add a big card of the same name, it is rendered with the same small cards still attached, even though it has a completely new id, using `uniqId()`

So TL;DR, my techniques for targeting a specific index are console logging properly, but the object is being assigned incorrectly, by name, which I'm not evaluating at all in my code.

Comment: you are doing `const newShips = [...this.props.shipInfo];` and then  `const upgrades = newShips[shipIndex].upgrades;` at the end of these 2 statements it won't matter that you first copied the state because `[...this.props.shipInfo]`is a new array, but the elements are the same as `this.props.shipInfo`, so you will be editing the original `this.props.shipInfo[shipIndex].upgrades`

Comment: to better help you I would need to see a more complete component structure.
to know how and where this handler is called.